Work done by a spring on objects of different masses
If a spring is compressed between two trolleys of masses m and 4m on a smooth one dimensional surface is released, will the work done on both masses be equal regardless of the trolleys' masses?

A simple thought experiment would say NO, but it depends on some clarification.  Work done on one of the masses is equal to the integral of spring force over displacement.  In the limit of one of the two masses being infinitely massive, although the forces at both ends of the spring are equal, there would be no displacement on the massive end, so all the work would be done on the lighter mass.  I believe this means that the work on each mass will only be equal in the case of equal masses.
But this is only considering the initial displacement of the spring to its rest length.  If you have no friction and the masses oscillate over time, then you are down to one of those vocabulary questions where how exactly you define "work done on/by" could lead you back to an answer of zero net work on both masses when you return to the original initial state.

Momentum is conserved. So with trolley $A$ and $B$:
$$ p_A + p_B = 0 $$
hence:
$$ p_A = - p_B \equiv p $$
So the kinetic energies are:
$$T_A = \frac{p^2}{2M_A} $$
$$T_B = \frac{p^2}{2M_B} $$
which are only equal if $M_A = M_B$.
